# How can I use Jrebel 6.4.6 with maven project via Intellij?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I am using Jrebel 6.4.6. I have maven-web project.
How can I use jrebel for the project in Intellij?
*ps: I can NOT see any Jrebel options for the project*

Comment: Do you use community or ultimate edition of IntelliJ?

Comment: @binoternary I use ultimate edition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the JRebel plugin for IntelliJ if you haven't already.

See [this guide](https://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/quickstart/intellij/) for how to get started with the plugin.

Comment: I already installed the JRebel plugin. It does not work with Maven build. I mean that Jrebel only works well with the Idea build process.

Comment: @Peter JRebel doesn't need to work with Maven build process. The only thing is that during the build you may want to generate rebel.xml for every module of the Maven project - then you can configure JRebel maven plugin to automate that. JRebel itself though is an agent that is hooked into JVM process and you can configure it either by starting from IDE or from the command line. If you start the process with mvn command then you can add the -javaagent parameter into MAVEN_OPTS - that should work fine.